# Hard extendability problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, graph-theory, np-hardness

In extendability problem, we are given part of the solution and we want to decide whether we can extend it to a complete solution. Some extendability problems are efficiently solvable while other extendability problems transform an easy problem to hard one.

For instance, Konig-Hall theorem states that all cubic bipartite graphs
are 3-edge colorable but the [extendability version becomes $NP$-complete](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.10088/full) if we are given the colors of some edges.

I'm looking for a survey paper of hard extendability problems where the *the base problem* is easy (or trivial as in the above example).

Comment: I don't know if there is a survey of extendability problems, but at least one very well studied such problem is *precoloring extension*. You'll find many hits searching for the problem name.

Comment: Two notes: 1) are there NPC problems that cannot be transformed to a hard extendability problem? 2) I think that it would be very interesting also a survey that is focused only on extendability problems, for which the "base" problem has unknown complexity (e.g. the monochromatic rectangle free problem, or some puzzle games)

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi Very interesting comment. 1) I do not know any such example. 2) GI is a good candidate and I guess its extendability problem is NP-complete.

Comment: A fact: GI-extendability is GI-complete. Indeed even if you don't allow an *empty partial solution* (you should specify it in the question) you can add a large enough $K_n$ to both graphs and give as partial solution the mapping between the two $K_n$. I'll think if it can be NPC!

Comment: The extension version of NP-hard problems are NP-hard (do greedy search for certificate using the oracle).

Comment: @Kaveh My base problem is not NP-hard. It is trivial since the edges of any bridgeless cubic graph can be partitioned into edge-disjoint paths $P_4$

Comment: the reply was to Marizo's question.

Comment: Given that there seems unlikely to be a survey, and given the list that is starting to build in the comments, do you want to make this CW and ask for a big list (where a survey would of course be an acceptable answer)?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow No need for CW. I am only interested in examples where the "base problem" is easy. The base problem mentioned in the post is trivial. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi: GI-extendability is indeed GI-complete (not just GI-hard, which I believe is what you meant to say), and therefore not NP-complete unless PH collapses. GI-extendability can be rephrased as vertex-colored GI (where vertices of a given color can only map to vertices of the same color), which reduces to GI in a number of ways (one of which is to attach gadgets to vertices, similar to your $K_n$ idea).

Comment: Okay, no need for CW. But still: do you want a big list of easy problems whose extendability problem is NP-complete, or do you only want a survey, or do you want an answer to your specific question as to whether the particular extendability problem mentioned in the question is hard?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow  I want an answer to my question? That is my priority. Your example is welcomed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

n-coloring the n x n Sudoku graph is trivial, but if some of the colors are given to you (the extendability version) it becomes NP-complete.

By the "Sudoku graph" I mean the natural graph whose associated coloring problem is Sudoku. Namely, suppose $n=k^2$ is a square. The graph will have $n^2$ vertices, which we will denote by $(r_1, r_2; c_1, c_2)$ for $r_1,r_2,c_1,c_2 \in [k] = [\sqrt{n}]$. For each fixed $(r_1,r_2)$, the vertices $(r_1, r_2; *, *)$ form an $n$-clique; for each fixed $(c_1, c_2)$ the vertices $(*, *; c_1, c_2)$ form an $n$-clique; and for each fixed $(r_1, c_1)$, the vertices $(r_1, *; c_1, *)$ form an $n$-clique.